# Angular - (Valid JSON) fromJSON - Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I'm having some difficulties implementing a post request to my Spring Rest service running on localhost.

Now the request and the service both work, the current problem is that I keep receiving the same error, saying that my JSON is incorrect.

### The code which I use for creating the JSON request:

```
$scope.addComment = function(){
var url = "http://localhost:8080/evenement/"+evenementId+"/deelnemers/"+deelnemer.id+"/addComment";
  $http.post(url, {"content" : $scope.data.comment, "author":"testUser"}).then(function(res){
    $scope.response = res.data;
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

I tried removing the quotes, using single quotes and using no quotes, as answered on other questions with the same problem.

---

[image: Request Payload as shown in Developer Console including errormessage.]

Comment: So what is the exact string that is parsed?

Comment: Sounds like it is throwing a wobbly over the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - can you inspect the raw bytes received?

Comment: @Filburt I would like to but I do not know how, if you can show me what to do I can haha, Im using chrome fyi

Comment: @zerkms that probably will be `{"content" : $scope.data.comment, "author":"testUser"}` where the  `$scope.data.comment` is replaced by a value out of a input field.

Comment: But I'm kinda new to angular so I wouldn't be able to guarantee that

Comment: It is complaining about being unable to parse the **response** as JSON, which we're not seeing here.

Comment: That could be the problem

Comment: @deceze it is the problem, if you'll submit that as an answer I'll accept it and close this question, I was returning plain text instead of JSON

Comment: Could you show us also the network/respose tab, on the developer tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that it is unable to parse the **response** as JSON. Your server is not returning valid JSON to this request.